# Unity gives a gameobject Don't destroy on Load

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I am trying to load a scene, but I stumble across a problem with the 'don't destroy on load' function. I never called a 'dont destroy on load' function on my gameobject.

Is it possible that there always has to be a DDOL object?

[This is how it looks like before runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x28MJ.png)

[and here it is with runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rY4eL.png)

Tour is an Empty gameobject with no reference at all to a script, so I don't get why it is an DDOL object while running.

Hope you guys can help me.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: something in your code is making it dont destroy.. it doesnt do it by default on anything - it maybe something in  component you loaded that you didnt write such as the manager etc

Comment: I just figured out it is because of the player in the Tour object. It is a prefab from steamvr. When i unchild it, it deletes the whole Tour object but not the player. i only have to figure out to delete the player and then the whole scene is clear! Thank you for your help!